# Executing a query with no search term causes System.StackOverflow Exception in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I 'm dealing with a query which results in above mentioned error when called with no or limited search string.
The table is 30k records big and when the query is fired with no search string I would expect the database to return all records and have Visual Studio put them in a table (ASP.net), however, if the query is fired like above the **StackOverflow** **error** is returned :(

If I fire the query with a more specific search string the script seems to work normal and results are being returned as expected.

I have been googling and all seems to point to an infinite loop or recursion but returning records make me believe it might be another problem.

The query:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_cstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr;

if (mode == "zoek_met_zoekterm")
{   
    cmd.CommandText = "select W1.id, W1.soort_brief, W1.omschrijving, W1.referentie, W1.url, W1.factuur, W3.naam, W3.klantnummer, W4.omschrijving AS w4_omschr, W4.referentie AS w4_ref, substring(W1.referentie,6,2) as w1_jaar, W1.parent AS w1_parent from brief W1 left join brief W4 on W1.parent = W4.id join klant W3 on W3.klantnummer = W1.klantnummer where W1.referentie in (select referentie from brief where substring(referentie,6,2) = @jaar) and (W3.klantnummer like @zoekterm or W1.referentie like @zoekterm or W1.omschrijving like @zoekterm or W3.naam like @zoekterm or W4.omschrijving like @zoekterm) order by W1.id";

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@zoekterm", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + (string)parameters["zoekterm"] + "%";
    string jaar = parameters["jaar"].ToString();
    jaar = jaar.Substring(2, 2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@jaar", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = jaar;//(Int32)parameters["jaar"];
    base.LogQuery(cmd);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        CBrief brief = new CBrief();
        brief.Id = dr.GetInt32(0);
        brief.SoortBrief = (Enums.SoortBrief)dr.GetInt32(1);
        brief.Omschrijving = Functies.Decrypt(dr.GetString(2), EncryptData);
        brief.Referentie = Functies.Decrypt(dr.GetString(3), EncryptData);
        brief.Url = Functies.Decrypt(dr.GetString(4), EncryptData);
        brief.Factuur = (Enums.SoortDocument)dr.GetInt32(5);
        brief.Klantnummer = dr.GetInt32(7);
        if (dr.GetString(2).Length == 0)
        {
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(9) && !dr.IsDBNull(8))
                brief.Omschrijving = dr.GetString(9) + " " + dr.GetString(8);
        }
        ret_value.Add(brief);

    }
    dr.Close();
    dr.Dispose();
}
```

And the function that calls the query:

```
public List<CBrief> GetBriefOverzicht(string zoekterm, int jaar)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("zoekterm", zoekterm);
    parameters.Add("jaar", jaar);
    if (zoekterm.Length == 0)
    {
        return _dal.brief_search(parameters, "geen_invoer");
    }
    return _dal.brief_search(parameters, "zoek_met_zoekterm");
}
```

And last but not least the function that builds the table to display in the web application:

```
protected void Bzoeken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string zoekterm = TBzoekterm.Text;
    DateTime nu = DateTime.Now;
    int jaar = nu.Year;

    List<CBrief> brieven = br_rbs.GetBriefOverzichtWijzigen(zoekterm);

    StringBuilder overzicht = new StringBuilder("<table class=\"tabel-beheer-1\">");

    foreach (CBrief b in brieven)
    {
        List<CBijlage> bijlagen = new List<CBijlage>();
        CKlant k = sec.GetKlant(b.Klantnummer);
        string klantnaam = k.Naam;
        string richting = "";
        if (b.OmschrijvingAanwezig == true)
        {
            bijlagen = br_rbs.GetBijlagenBrieven(b.Id);
        }
        if (b.SoortBrief == Enums.SoortBrief.Inkomend) richting = "van: "; else richting = "naar: ";
        // MG10082017 Ik heb hier twee icoontjes in elkaar geflanst om te testen. Deze moeten nog aangepast worden zodat ze in het geheeel passen. 
        overzicht.AppendLine("<tr><td><a href=\"test.nl\"><img src=\"/images/bg/document.jpg\" alt=\"open document\"></a></td><td><a href=\"detail_brief.aspx?id=" + b.Id + "\"><img src=\"/images/bg/detail.jpg\" alt=\"details\"></a></td><td><b>" + b.Referentie + "</b></td><td><i>" + b.SoortBrief.ToString() + " " + richting + "</i> " + klantnaam + "</td><td><b> " + b.Factuur.ToString() + ":</b> " + b.Omschrijving  /*+"</td><td>"*/);
        if (bijlagen.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CBijlage bijl in bijlagen)
            {
                overzicht.AppendLine("</br><a href =\"" + bijl.Url + "\"> " + bijl.Naam + "</a>");
            }

        }
    }
    overzicht.AppendLine("</td></tr></table>");
    Loverzicht.Text = overzicht.ToString();
}
```

The error usually points to: System.Web.dll or w3wp.exe (when not ran in debug mode). If my assumption is wrong and it seems to be an infinite loop or recursion, how am I going to find this?

The query works flawless in MS-SQL management console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is not an infinite loop!
The Problem lies in the UI.
You can't display 30k units at once without a StackOverflow-Exception.
You should call pages of maybe 20 or 30 units at once with an pageIndex.
This way, your application will perform better and avoid such errors.

Comment: This makes sense! I am wondering how this works, what causes the overflow exception? Is it caused by transferring the results from the query into the table for display? I would think that getting the result set from the databse should not be a problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly where the Overflow happens, but if you can add the Exception Stack we may find out.

Comment: I wasn't able to produce a decent Exception Stack but after some further investigation this: `Loverzicht.Text = overzicht.ToString();` seemed to be the problem. The query returned results as I expected but adding them to the control didn't work that great. I solved the issue with a GridView control. I know best practice of paginating is handling this server-side but I'll go with this solution for now.